# При подщëте в итоге пишет 0

Tags: python, tkinter

Вот код

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Hello wold")
window.geometry("300x300")       

def show_message():
    la = tk.Label(text=result)
    la.grid(column=1,row=3)
e = tk.Entry(window,width=10)
e.grid(column=1,row=1)
e=int()
d=70
result = e*70
b = tk.Button(window,text="если готово нажми",command=show_message)
b.grid(column=1,row=2)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. О каком «подщëте» речь? Почему вы ожидаете, что должно быть не 0? И где и когда вы это ожидаете?

Comment: В функции def выводиться переменная в которой умножены два числа переменная e и 70

Comment: Функция show_message выводит значение переменной result, которая имеет значение `e*70`, а так как значение переменной e всегда равно 0, то результат умножения на 0 всегда равен 0

Comment: По идеи е = данным ввода пользователя, как мне это справить

Comment: Научитесь в tk вводить данные с экрана. Поле ввода, кнопка.

Answer (score 1):

`e = int()` все равно что `e = 0`.
Тогда `e*70` все равно что `0*70`, а это уже `0`.

Comment: А что тогда надо сделать? По типу e =int(e). Кстати спасибо за обьяснение

Comment: @нутиппабг это вы нам расскажите, что вы хотите сделать-то

Comment: начал изучать тк и захотел сделать конвертор валют из долларов в рубли

Comment: @нутиппабг а зачем это вы используете переменную `е` и как объект `tkinter`'a и для свои нужд в "подщёте"?

Comment: Всмысле, что сделать надо